# Psycopg2 install with pip works but cannot import module on OS X 10.9

Tags: python, osx-mavericks, psycopg2

I've installed psycopg2 with

```
pip install psycopg2
```

and it worked just fine. The install output had a couple of warning along the lines of

```
In file included from ./psycopg/psycopg.h:33:
./psycopg/config.h:71:13: warning: unused function 'Dprintf' [-Wunused-function]
static void Dprintf(const char *fmt, ...) {}
            ^
1 warning generated.
```

but in the end it says

```
Successfully installed psycopg2
```

and it also appears when I run `pip list`.

Now when I try to import it in python I get an error:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

Why can't Python import the module if it was successfully installed?

(Python 2.7.5 was installed with Homebrew. psycopg2 was installed with pip.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OS X comes with Python 2.7.5 already; when you install Python with Homebrew, it puts a newer version in a different place without touching the built-in one. Homebrew's Python also comes with Pip, whereas OS X's doesn't. What's going on here is, you're using Homebrew's `pip` to install psycopg2, then running OS X's `python` and trying to import it.

Run `/usr/local/bin/python` (the full path to Homebrew's Python), and try `import psycopg2` from there.

If that works, you need to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` variable, so that your shell finds Homebrew's Python before the OS X one every time. If you use Bash (the default shell in OS X), you can do this by putting the following in your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

To make sure that you're running the right Python in scripts, use the following shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

`env` will search `PATH` for Python and run the script with the first one it finds, the same as typing `python` from your shell. Bash scripts and such should inherit the `PATH` variable and find the right python without changes.

You can also hardcode the path to Homebrew Python in your shebang line (`#!/usr/local/bin/python`), but this means your script will only work on OS X machines with a Homebrew Python installed, and is best avoided.

Comment: Thanks Adam. When I run `$ usr/local/bin/python` in Terminal I can actually import psycopg2. _But_ when I try to make the change you suggested to the `.bash_profile` no changes take effect. I used `$ source .bash_profile` and then `$ python` but the old python still comes up. How can I make brew's python the default one in Terminal? (Also, when I run a python script file, say from a shell script I wrote, how can I make sure that it is called with brew's python?)

Comment: I just realised I wrote `set` when I meant to write `export`; that should make Bash find the right one by default. I've edited my answer to fix this and also answer your other questions.